# Sample code in Touretzky's book causes Error at Let*

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Sample code in page 144 of [Touretzky's `Lisp` book](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) causes error on my environment. Is anything wrong with how I run?

```
(defun price-change (old new)
  (let* ((diff (- new old))
     (proportion (/ diff old))
     (percentage (* proportion 100.0)))
    (list ’widgets ’changed ’by percentage
       ’percent))
)
```

Here's the error. I don't understand why string "widgets" is evaluated...

```
Break 5 [7]> (price-change 1.25 1.35)

*** - LET*: variable ’WIDGETS has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of ’WIDGETS.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for ’WIDGETS.
ABORT          :R3      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R4      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R5      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R6      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R7      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R8      Abort main loop
```

Environment: Ubuntu 11.10, GNU CLISP 2.49

Comment: How are you even getting that character? What are you using to edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the quote character *apostrophe*: `'`. You did not. You have used a right quotation mark.

Comment: Thanks. The code I cited is what I just copied & pasted from the original pdf file.

Comment: @IsaacS: yes this could be done by the type-setting process. Be careful when you copy code from the book. Note that parts of the code are available here:  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Lisp/